# Rythmbox is playing but not showing up on window or with ctl tab

Tags: 15.04, lubuntu

Me again.  I am having a goofy issue with Rythymbox player.  I could use vlc but I have this issue and its getting under my ocd.  I am using Lubuntu 15.04 lts and Trying to run rythmbox.  It starts and runs fine, playing through my playlist now. but the problem is that it does not show up on my screen anywhere even with other programs all closed. I Use CTL-tab and it can not be selected.  Any clues?  I searched the feed but found nothing. thank you.